# AEM 6.5 Knowing if an image has a focus point set?

Tags: aem

Is there a way to find in AEM (/crx/de) if an image in assets has a focus point set?
I looked in [image]
but I cannot find a metadata property for Focus point. Any help is appreciated.

Also how does one go about saving the "Set Focus Point" option on the image? I do not see any Save on that dialog.

Comment: did you try custom Metadata Profile to apply on image it will give you option to store custom attribute

Comment: Thanks @Vikka Yes, I believe it is not saved as a property on the node.